# How to get the task version for an Azure DevOps Pipelines task?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-task-lib

I have an Azure Pipelines Task which uses the azure-pipelines-task-lib (https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib) and need to get the version of the task from within my task code (TypeScript). I figured there would be an easy way to do this using the azure-pipelines-task-lib library but if there is, I haven't found it.

The version is specified in the task.json file which is packaged up into the artifact that is built when you're publishing a task and I could parse that easily enough, it just seems a bit kludgy to do so. Does anyone know of a better way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to get task version using the azure-pipelines-task-lib, parse the task.json file is the usual way we can do currently.

Comment: How do I find the task.json in a deployed task? I can easily parse the task.json in my dev environment, but once I run it in an Azure Pipeline, the task.json does not appear to be anywhere where I can read it. Is there some path I can look in to find this file in a deployed Pipeline?

Thanks

Comment: You can try to get directory of the current folder that the task execute and read the `task.json` file.

Comment: @maxjeffos Are you able to get `task.json` file?

Comment: Hi @Cece Dong - MSFT, yes I was able to get the task.json file using this:
```
const taskJsonPath = path.join(__dirname, "..", "task.json");
```
With that I just parsed out the version from the task file by first using `JSON.parse(...)` and then grabbing the Major/Minor/Patch fields.
Thanks!